# C programming: write() integers to a text file

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I m trying to write a couple of integers on a text file using write() sys call, but insead of numbers i got strange symbols (**00\00\00\00\00\00**).

Gedit is telling me that there is an issue with encoding and that the file is not in UTF-8. I m compiling with gcc which should has the UTF-8 codec set by default. I solved the '\00' by changing the sizeof(i) with 1 but i cant resolve the numbers.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
   int fd=open("test.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
   int i = 2;
   write(fd, &i, sizeof(i)); }
```

Comment: The `write()` system call does no translation of the data.  You would need to use or simulate `snprintf()` to convert the binary value to text and then write the string, maybe with a newline, to the file.

Comment: You problem is that you actually don't want to write integers. What you really want is to write *text* which represents integers. You need to learn the difference.

Answer (score 3):

You have to understand how numbers are represented in a computer:
When you read `2` on the screen, what is actually held in memory is the number 50.

This is the code for the character `2` in the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

The actual number 2, does not correspond to a printable character, that is a symbol you can read on the screen, so different text editors like Gedit will behave differently: some will show squares or dots, other will show the number with some escaping like the '\' character.

UTF-8 is actually backwards compatible with ASCII, as it gives the English alphabet, numbers and some other characters same codes as ASCII.

An integer variable holds the actual number with which the computer can perform calculations, and not the characters you as a human can read.

If you are using a 32 bit OS, `int` in C will be 32 bits or 4 bytes.
Since you most likely using x86 processor, the number will be reresented in [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) order.

So, when you write these bytes to file with your code, the file will look like this on disk:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Gedit will try to read it as 4 characters, but it can not print them, so it shows you their value preceded by the '\' charter so you will know that these are special non printable characters.

There are two ways to use `write()` and still get a text representation you want.
First, you need an array of `char` to create a string representation of the number.

Then, you can do one of two things:

1. Cheat and use `sprintf` to easily format the number in to a string.
2. Do the work yourself with a loop and some simple math, and convert each decimal digit in the number to it's ASCII character.
   Here is a hint: just add 0x30 (hexadecimal 30)

Answer (score 1):

`write` will write the binary representation of the `int`, e.g. 8 bytes forming the 64 bits of an integral value, directly to the file. There is no conversion into ASCII or UTF8 "characters" as you'd expect when opening the file with a text editor. The integral value `2` in binary is `0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02`, and that's what you "see" in your file. A textual representation would be `0x32`, i.e. the ASCII value of digit `2`.

Use `snprintf` to convert an integral value to a textual representation and write that to the file then:

```
int i = 2;
char str[50];
snprintf(str, 50, "%d\n", i);
write(fd, str, strlen(str));
```

Comment: There is additional weirdness if the computer is little-endian (such as Intel), because the bytes are written to the file in reverse order: so a 0x00000000000000002 would produce 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 in the file.

Answer (score 1):

A much easier to way to write to a text file is to use fopen:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    /* Open a plain file for writing */
    FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "w");
    if (fp) {
        int i = 2;
        fprintf(fp, "%d\n", i);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

if you need to use open(2), you could do it like this:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int fd = open("test.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (fd != -1) {
        int i = 2;
        char tempbuf[13];
        int bytes = sprintf(tempbuf, "%d\n", i);
        if (bytes > 0)
            write(fd, tempbuf, bytes);
        close(fd);
    }
}
```

You'll need to figure out the proper buffer sizes for the integers you are writing, and the encoding.

Comment: what is  FILE *int fp = fopen("test.txt", "w"); ? fp is a file pointer, what is *int. I don't think you can use int with fp

Comment: Haha, good catch.